# Cardboard SDK Crash

Tags: google-cardboard

Just download Cardboard demo. Build to Android device. Launch it and get a crash log. Anyone know the issue?

Thanks.

```
01-24 15:24:12.468    7271-7271/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
Unity version     : 4.6.0b20
Device model      : Xiaomi HM 1SW
Device fingerprint: Xiaomi/armani/armani:4.3/JLS36C/JHCMIBH45.0:user/release-keys
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/vrtoolkit/cardboard/CardboardDeviceParams
        at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.HeadMountedDisplayManager.createCardboardDeviceParams(HeadMountedDisplayManager.java:214)
        at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.HeadMountedDisplayManager.<init>(HeadMountedDisplayManager.java:54)
        at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardView.init(CardboardView.java:768)
        at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardView.<init>(CardboardView.java:263)
        at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.plugins.unity.UnityCardboardActivity.onCreate(UnityCardboardActivity.java:184)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5135)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2182)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1263)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5162)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:756)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:572)
        at miui.dexspy.DexspyInstaller.main(DexspyInstaller.java:171)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you find a way to solve it i am facing same issue ..

Answer (score 2):

You need to add libprotobuf-java-2.3-nano.jar. Its in the 
\cardboard-java-master\CardboardSample\libs with cardboard.jar
Fixed it for me.